# Can anyone say what is wrong with this code?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT Fname,Lname,Address
FROM employee
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
FROM dependent
WHERE Ssn=Essn AND Relationship='Son' AND NOT Relationship='Daughter')
GROUP BY Ssn
```

I'm trying to List the first name, last name, and address of all employees who have a son as a dependent but do not have a daughter as a dependent.

Comment: You should tag it with what version of mysql you are using instead of the tool you are using to write the query with.

Comment: Should be using `<> relationship='Daughter'`, and not `NOT`, I believe.

Comment: @SeanBrookins - I suspect they are equivalent (except maybe for NULLs.)

Comment: Please consider reading the following articles: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (Help Centre)_ and _[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) (Meta DBA.SE)_. Currently your question doesn't contain enough information and might be closed as [**unclear what you're asking**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). Add some sample data and what you expect to be returned.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exists` and `not exists`

```
select ...
  from employee e
 where exists (
      select * from dependent where ssn = e.ssn and relationship = 'Son'
 )
 and not exists (
    select * from dependent where ssn = e.ssn and relationship = 'Daughter'
 )
```

You can also achieve this with a `left join`

```
select ...
  from employee e
  left join dependent d
    on e.ssn = d.ssn
   and d.relationship = 'Son'
  left join dependent d2
    on e.ssn = d2.essn
   and d2.relationship = 'Daughter'
 where d.ssn is not null
   and d2.ssn is null
```

Comment: Thank you SO much

Answer (score 1):

> what is wrong with this code?

Wrong point is:

```sql
WHERE ... Relationship='Son' AND NOT Relationship='Daughter'
```

1. The conditions are applied to THE SAME RECORD. So when `Relationship` is equal to `'Son'` then it is not equal `'Daughter'` in this record automatically.
2. The conditions do not check any another record. So if a record where `Relationship='Son'` exists then `SELECT` will return (this) record regardless of the existence of another record for the same employee with `Relationship='Daughter'`.

> I'm trying to List the first name, last name, and address of all employees who have a son as a dependent but do not have a daughter as a dependent.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Fname, Lname, Address
FROM employee e
JOIN dependent d1 ON d1.essn = e.ssn
WHERE d1.Relationship = 'Son'
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                 FROM dependent d2
                 WHERE d2.essn = e.ssn 
                   AND d2.relationship = 'Daughter' )
```